# How to infer surprisingly "missing" data in a large set of strings. Or nerds do unique (but sane) baby names

Tags: machine-learning, text-processing, data-generation

I was thinking about this problem the other day when trying to find an applicable email address for my very common name.

Let's say I had all the names of the roughly 150 million men in the United States in a file, and I wanted to figure out "men who don't exist but sound like they should". That is, I wanted to figure out a combination of names (First, Middle, Last) that exist without a person being named that combination in my record of all names. Let's say I appreciate the advantages of unique names but don't want any of the disadvantages of unfamiliarity and mispronunciation.

Of course I could make up a name like "Nickleback Sunshine Cheeseburger" and reasonably suspect that nobody would be named this combination but that may confuse people so I want names that exist in the set. So names like "Chao-Lin" which have different languages of origin although they may appear with the last name "Jones" would not be as likely to appear with Jones and seem more consistent with a last name of similar language origin like "Chao-Lin Kuo". José is more likely to appear with Gonzalez than Patel and so on.

Of course any of these notions would have to be re-enforced by the structure of the data.

So an example would be if "John Marcus Black" doesn't exist, that would be interesting because all names in the name are common and appear together frequently, just not in that order.

The first thing that came into my mind was some sort of trie or directed graph that is weighted by frequency but that only really works for an "autocomplete" like feature where what we are looking for is not actually present in the set. I was thinking about suffix trees as well but not sure if this is a good use case.

I'm sure there is a machine learning algorithm that would be sufficient in finding these names but I don't know very many.

Bonus, the most normal unique name given a necessary last name. Given a starting name like "Smith", come up with most surprising missing names.

**tl;dr 1. Given all the names of men in the US in a file, find n names that probably should exist but don't. Also: some men have middle names, some don't.**

Answer (score 0):

The obvious choice would be character level Markov chains.

That won't prevent the generation of existing names, and of profanity, though. I.e., it might combine FUnk and niCK.

You could then rank the results by some surprisingness measure. E.g., fbased on character bigram/trigram frequencies.